# Highlight missing closing brackets in TeXworks

Tags: texworks, brackets

Is there the possibility to perform a check in TeXworks to see if there are any missing closing brackets?

With this I also mean brackets not related to specific latex commands (e.g. `(` and `)`).

Comment: To whoever cast the close vote: Please don't just vote to close without leaving a comment explaining your reason to do so.

Comment: This is from texworks manual and maybe be helpful: "A frequent error is to forget a closing symbol: parenthesis, bracket, square bracket.
TEXworks helps with a tool to show the pairs of symbols: when one move over one
of these symbols its complementary is brieﬂy highlighted in orange. One can also,
when one is inside a block like this, one can ask to select the block by Edit / balance
delimiters or by its short-cut [Ctrl+B]. Thus one immediately sees the scope of the
block."

Comment: This may be a very basic approach, but how about just using a search to count the number of ( and the number of ) to check that the number matches?

Comment: @myrtille Good suggestion, but it still doesn't help to locate the problem. In a document of 10k lines it can't be done manually :)